# Is it good to return everything in 1 json?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

Below is my json which is return from a web service :

```
{
      "variantId": 100,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "attachments":[],
          "attachmentLogs":[],
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 16,
          "attachments":[],
          "attachmentLogs":[],
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "variantId": 200,
      "tests": [
        {
          "testId": 15,
          "attachments":[],
          "attachmentLogs":[],
          "flag" : true
        },
        {
          "testId": 16,
          "attachments":[],
          "attachmentLogs":[],
          "flag" : true
        }
      ]
    }
```

Right now my web service method doesnt returns attachment and attachmentLogs in my json but each test will have a list of attachment and attachmentLogs and for every variant it will be different.

**For Eg**: VariantId=100 and testId=15 will have different attachment and attachmentLogs.VariantId=200 and testId=15 will have different attachment and attachmentLogs.

Now if user want to see attachments and attachmentsLogs for VariantId=100 and TestId=15 then user click on button and i make a 2 server calls to get attachments and attachmentLogs every time when user clicks on button.

So here my question is should i get attachment and attachmentLogs in my huge json only or right now what i am doing is the better way.

Actually i am thinking like having a such huge json doesnt add any performance overhead on browser or doesnt put any load on browser.

Can anybody suggest me what will be the better way to handle this scenario??

Comment: i will delete the question if i will get to know that why this question needs to be closed or deleted.

Comment: If you click on the `close ()` link under your question, you will see the reasons for the close votes

Answer (score 1):

If you need these logs/attachments each time when you are calling your service, you can add them, but if they are optional it will be better to add just references with IDs/URLs of these huge files to fetch them if necessary by separate requests.

In this case you will have faster response time and will not send unnecessary data on each request to the service.

Comment: Actually when user will click on button like say user wants to see attachment and attachmentLogs for VariantId=100 and testId=15 then and then only i will make 2 call to server to get attachment and attachmentLogs

Comment: If you are showing these logs on demand, just send references to these logs in your JSON and make additional call to fetch this large objects only after user's request.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the attachments and their logs when the user clicks the button then your current solution is good.
Because, If you get all the attachment and attachment logs at once, you will have the data but that data may not be used at all, so loss of resources.
If suppose there are 50 variants and user is interested only in 2 of them, then why get data for all.

But if you can implement a pagination kind of thing, the other solution would make sense. Suppose you show only 5 variants at a time, the next five on the next api call, it would be better to have all the data at once.